# Selecting specific columns while writing it to CSV file

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a CSV file using a dataset. I need to only select few columns from my dataset not all the columns.

I am using below code but it's writing all the columns in the data row to CSV file.

I need to write only first, third and fifth columns to the CSV file and ignore second and fourth columns.

```
For Each row As DataRow In dsRefs.Tables(0).Rows
     For i As Integer = 0 To dsRefs.Tables(0).Columns.Count() -
            csvWriter.NextRecord()
      Next
Next
```

Comment: [DataView.ToTable(String, Boolean, String())](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.8) (`dsRefs.Tables(0).DefaultView.ToTable(...)`).

Comment: The code you've posted in the question doesn't do what you say that it does. Can you post your real code?

Comment: @Jimi - Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A technique to resolve this might be;

```vb
Dim listOfColums = (From dtR As DataRow In dsRefs.Tables(0).Rows
                    Select r1 = dtR.Item(0), 'first
                           r2 = dtR.Item(2), 'third
                           r3 = dtR.Item(4)) 'fifth


Using sWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\YouurPathToSaveCsv\YourFileCsv.csv")

    Dim divider As String = ";"

    If listOfColums IsNot Nothing AndAlso listOfColums.Count > 0 Then

        For Each okList In listOfColums
            Dim cRow As String = Strings.Join({okList.r1, okList.r2, okList.r3}, divider)
            Console.WriteLine(cRow)
            sWriter.WriteLine(cRow)
        Next

    End If

End Using
```